# How to iterate over a SOLR shard which has over 100 million documents?

Tags: search, solr, lucene

I would like to iterate over all these documents without having to load the entire result in memory which seems to be the case apparently - QueryResponse.getResults() returns SolrDocumentList which is an ArrayList.

Can't find anything in the documentation. Am using SOLR 4.

Note on the background of problem: I need to do this when adding a new SOLR shard to the existing shard cluster. In that case, I would like to move some documents from the existing shards to the newly added shard(s) based on consistent hashing. Our data grows constantly and we need to keep introducing new shards.

Comment: Using range query on an indexed field would be a good way to accomplish this? Even if the particular field is not unique?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the 'rows' and 'start' query params to paginate a result set.  Query first with start = 0, then start = rows, start = 2*rows, etc. until you reach the end of the complete result set.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#start

Comment: Yes, that is what I am broadly doing. On top, I am querying and sorting on an indexed field. Not using "start" as that slows down the fetch over big result set.I was wondering if SOLR provides a cursor like functionality existing in databases.

Comment: No, I don't believe so.  You could do something about the hit from progressing start values.  Since you are sorting on some value, you could use a range query to only fetch records appearing after some sorted identifier field, and thus always be retrieving from start=0 while paging through results.

Answer (score 0):

I have a possible solution I'm testing:
[Solr paging 100 Million Document result set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27623664/solr-paging-100-million-document-result-set)

pasted:
I am trying to do deep paging of very large result sets (e.g., over 100 million documents) using a separate indexed field (integer) into which I insert a random variable (between 0 and some known MAXINT). When querying large result sets, I do the initial field query with no rows returned and then based on the count, I divide the range 0 to MAXINT in order to get on average PAGE_COUNT results by doing the query again across a sub-range of the random variable and grabbing all the rows in that range. Obviously the actual number of rows will vary but it should follow a predictable distribution.